# Using Member Type from Template Parameter

Tags: c++

I'm interested in doing some thing like this.

```
template<typename Clock>
struct A {
    Clock::time_point time;
}

A<chrono::steady_clock> a;
```

However this is not possible. How can I achieve this?

I think there maybe away around using this method in `Clock`'s context but what is the proper way to do this in general?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since `Clock::time_point` is a dependent type, you need the `typename` keyword

```
template<typename Clock>
struct A {
    typename Clock::time_point time;
};
```